# Select2 with Ajax + PHP

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select

I am trying to use select2 pulling data using ajax from php back end. I could not figure out the documentation as much as I would like to. I think i probably missed some taken for granted stuffs. Please can you help with a simple example. I started or like this...

**html**

```
<select id="select_proj" style="width:10em">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Search</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
$('select').select2();
        $("#select_proj").select2({
          ajax: {
              url: '../app/select_prj.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (term, page) {
              return {
                  select_proj: term, // search term
                  page: 10
              };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
              return {
                results: data.items
              };
            },
            cache: true
          },
          escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
          minimumInputLength: 1,
        });
```

**In php**

```
    $data_wildcardsearch = $_POST['term'];
```

is throwing error

> [**Notice**:  Undefined index: term in b>-----/app/select_prj.php on line **18**
> ]

Could you please help? Can you please share a sample code as well?

Comment: because you are passing ``term`` as ``select_proj`` .

Comment: its `$_POST['select_proj']; ` not `$_POST['term'];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **data()** function you must pass **'term'** as a key instead of **select_proj**.

```
$('select').select2();
        $("#select_proj").select2({
          ajax: {
              url: '../app/select_prj.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (term, page) {
              return {
                  term: term, // search term
                  page: 10
              };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
              return {
                results: data.items
              };
            },
            cache: true
          },
          escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
          minimumInputLength: 1,
        });
```

Then you can get it by:

```
$data_wildcardsearch = $_POST['term'];
```

Comment: That worked. Query executed and returned [{"PROJ_ID":10039,"0":10039},{"PROJ_ID":10038,"0":10038}] as expected. How can I get this rendered in select?

Comment: Post another question, this is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You have post **term** with key => **'select_proj'**. 
Change code as below,

```
$data_wildcardsearch = $_POST['select_proj'];
```

**OR**

```
data: {term: term, page: 10},
```